# Using OAuth for django, how to save username from google account to database

Tags: python, django, authentication, social-authentication

I have managed to use Google authentication in my django site. The problem is when I go to user profile which is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/username

for example if my google username is Chazefate then when I go to Profile then this site is not avaible, because it didn't save the user to database, I think.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/Chazefate

I am using django python social auth.

So the main question is how can I save this google user in my database.